# MySQL solution to concatenate multiple rows of text based on 2 matching IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL (5.5.65-MariaDB) and have an application which consists of a table, `generated_text_tbl`. The following is some sample data from this table.

```
-----------------------------------------------
id | substance_id | display_id | generated_text   
-----------------------------------------------
1  | 54           | 139        | foo
-----------------------------------------------
2  | 54           | 139        | bar
----------------------------------------------
3  | 1933         | 139        | baz
-----------------------------------------------  
4  | 38           | 27         | xyz
-----------------------------------------------
```

`id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field. The `substance_id` and `display_id` are foreign keys which refer to records in other tables (`substances.id` and `display.id` respectively).

I want to output the text from the `generated_text` field - separated with a HTML line break character (`<br>`) - if where matching `substance_id` and `display_id` rows exist. If there is no match (i.e. an individual row) then `generated_text` should still be output, but does not need the `<br>` character since there is nothing to separate.

I have a solution to this problem which works in PHP but I want a pure SQL solution if possible. I've written out the logic I have since this technically works, albeit in PHP.

For the example data above the correct output would be as follows:

- `foo<br>bar` : because there are 2 rows where the `substance_id` and `display_id` match (both are 54 and 139 respectively).
- `baz` : there is only 1 row `WHERE substance_id = 1933 AND display_id = 139`.
- `xyz`: same logic as above, there is only 1 row `WHERE substance_id = 38 AND display_id = 27`.

Logically my PHP script works like this:

1. All unique `substance_id`'s are loaded into an array. Equivalent to SQL `SELECT DISTINCT(substance_id) FROM generated_text_tbl`.
2. All unique `display_id`'s are loaded into an array. Equivalent to SQL `SELECT DISTINCT(display_id) FROM generated_text_tbl`.
3. Loop through (1) with an inner loop on (2). This effectively cycles through every `substance_id` and `display_id` combination, i.e.:

   - `substance_id = 54 AND display_id = 139` (2 rows)
   - `substance_id = 54 AND display_id = 27` (0 rows)
   - `substance_id = 1933 AND display_id = 139` (1 row)
   - `substance_id = 1933 AND display_id = 27` (0 rows)
   - `substance_id = 38 AND display_id = 139` (0 rows)
   - `substance_id = 38 AND display_id = 27` (1 row)
4. It then obtains an array of `generated_text` based on the condition above. If the array size is greater than 1 element then a `<br>` character is added between each. If it's just 1 element then a `<br>` character isn't required because there is only 1 row of `generated_text` so nothing needs breaking up.

   ```
    // Store the output text
    $output = '';

    // e.g. $result contains MySQL rows WHERE substance_id = 54 AND display_id = 139
    if (sizeof($result) == 1) {
        $output = $result['generated_text'];
    } else {
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $output .= $value['generated_text'] . "<br>";
    }
        $output = (substr($output), 0, -4); // Remove trailing <br>
    }
   ```
5. The result of `var_dump($output)` for the above script is `foo<br>bar`, which is what I want.

Although this logically works it is inefficient (when there are thousands of rows in the `generated_text` table). Is there a pure SQL solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after something like that no ?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7649e/8)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  `substance_id` , 
  `display_id`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( `generated_text` SEPARATOR '<br>' ) as concact_text
from generated_text_tbl 
group by 
  `substance_id` , 
   `display_id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7649e/8/0)**:

```
| substance_id | display_id | concact_text |
|--------------|------------|--------------|
|           38 |         27 |          xyz |
|           54 |        139 |   foo<br>bar |
|         1933 |        139 |          baz |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT 
  `substance_id` , 
  `display_id`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( `generated_text` ORDER BY id DESC SEPARATOR '<br>') as concact_reverse_text
from generated_text_tbl 
group by 
  `substance_id` , 
   `display_id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7649e/8/1)**:

```
| substance_id | display_id | concact_reverse_text |
|--------------|------------|----------------------|
|           38 |         27 |                  xyz |
|           54 |        139 |           bar<br>foo |
|         1933 |        139 |                  baz |
```

Official Documentation : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: This works exactly how I need, thanks. Could you add some explanation about how it works? Presumably the `group by` clause is effectively doing the unique `substance_id` and `display_id` combinations that I described in the question? Is this why it doesn't need `distinct()`?

Comment: @Andy yes, `distinct` is just a `group by` on every field. Here you ask the DB to make a group by on your two columns and concat with a `<br>` separator if needed the `generated_text`. Usually group by is used for `sum` : you can get the sum for each ID / field you want ;)